# Find $f(x)$ from $f(3x + 1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem that I have to solve is:

If the following function is valid for every value of $x$

$$f(3x + 1) = 9x^2 + 3x$$

find the function $f(x)$ and prove that for every $x\in\mathbb R$ the following is valid: 
$$f(2x) - 4f(x) = 2x$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here $$f(3x+1)=3x(3x+1)=((3x+1)-1)(3x+1)$$ $$\implies f(x)=(x-1)x=x^2-x$$ $$\implies f(2x)-4f(x)=4x^2-2x-4x^2+4x=2x$$

In general, just let $3x+1=t$ and express $x$ in terms of $t$ and substitute in $f(t)$

Comment: Thanks, that's also what my theory says thanks for the solving the starting process :)

Comment: I did the math $$ x = ( w - 1 ) / 3 $$ and i have concluded to this $$ f(w) = w^2 - 2w + 1 + ( 3w - 3 ) / 3 $$  however there is an f(x) missing what should i do ??

Comment: $f(w)=w^2-2w+1+\frac{3(w-1)}{3}=w^2-2w+1+w-1=w^2-w$.Here, $w$ is just a dummy variable , so you can substitute $x$ for $w$ which gives $f(x)=x^2-x$. Keep in mind this new $x$ is different from previous $x$

Comment: +1 to both of you for the above comments (OP showing work and avatar following up)

Answer (score 8):

$$\begin{align} \overbrace{\dfrac{f(3x\!+\!1)}{3x\!+\!1} = 3x}^{\displaystyle \color{#c00}{\dfrac{f(z)}z\, =\, z\!-\!1}}\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{f(2x)\!-\!4f(x)}{2x} \,=\,&\ \color{#c64}{\dfrac{f(2x)}{2x}}-\, 2 \color{#C00}{\dfrac{f(x)}x} \\[.2em]
=&\,\ \color{#c64}{2x\!-\!1} -\ 2(\color{#C00}{x\!-\!1})\\
 =&\,\ 1\end{align}\qquad$$

**Remark** $ $ The point of presenting it like this is to emphasize how exploiting the innate *linear* structure serves to simplify the calculations (from nonlinear to linear). In less trivial problems this can yield much greater simplifications (e.g. in operator calculus  with $q$-difference operators).

Comment: Why would this be downvoted?

Comment: I like this, but it took me *quite a while* to grasp! (Of course, I'm rather low on the "totem pole"...)

Comment: @TheChaz I've added some color to help follow the logic.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I didn't have a problem with this answer; it just took a little to change gears from the approach I had in mind (which **avatar** put into an answer) to this approach :)

Comment: @TheChaz Yes, that's probably the most straightforward way to proceed. But I thought it might prove of interest to emphasize that there is additional structure that simplifies matters. Such structure comes to the fore when one studies $q$-difference operators and related operator calculus.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $3x+1=y \Rightarrow x= \frac{y-1}{3}$. So replace $x$ by $\frac{y-1}{3}$ and magic happens.